# Reading an array with value at end of file

Tags: c++, io

I am trying to read this file that looks like this (gameboard with 6 rows, 7 columns), and want to store the last value in a variable int called nextMove.

```
0000000
0000000
0000000
0000000
0000000
0000000
1
```

I'm reading this input file with this code:

```
ifstream f;
f.open(input_file);

int n;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    vector<int> row;
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        f >> n;
        row.push_back(n);
    }
    gameBoard.push_back(row);
}

f >> nextMove;

f.close();
```

code to print the gameBoard:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            cout << gameBoard[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

This is the output, and I do not understand why it gets fill with ones:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: What is `f`? Not specified here. Where's the printing code? This example is *far* from complete. We're left guessing how this happened.

Comment: How do you tell the quantity of rows and columns to read from the input file?

Comment: Please create a [mre] that we can compile and run ourselves.

Comment: As a *debug* statement, print the row before you append it to the game board.

Comment: `0000000` is a single `int` as far `std::istream`s are concerned. You may want to read character-by-character instead.

Comment: You are not validating whether `f >> ...` is successful before using the value being read.

Comment: @alterigel was correct.